# Calculation of text boxes

Tags: javascript

I am trying to calculate in Javascript.

I want to know the total of the values that are positive and the total of the values that are negative.

The script works when I am using only one textbox.

If the value of the first textbox is positive the script posts the value into textbox 'positive'. If the value of the second textbox is negative the script posts all the values into the textbox 'negative'.

**Example:**

First textbox:
50 +
Second textbox:
50 -

Total +:
(empty)

Total -:
100

What I want is the following:
First textbox:
50 +
Second textbox:
50 -

Total +:
50

Total -:
50

I am using the following script

HTML:

```
Price 1:<br />
<input type="text" id="p1" name="p[]">
<select id="pn1" name="pn[]">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="1">+</option>
  <option value="2">-</option>
</select>
<br />
Price 2:<br />
<input type="text" id="p2" name="p[]">
<select id="pn2" name="pn[]">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="1">+</option>
  <option value="2">-</option>
</select>
<br />
Price 3:<br />
<input type="text" id="p3" name="p[]">
<select id="pn3" name="pn[]">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="1">+</option>
  <option value="2">-</option>
</select>
<br /><br />
Total +:<br />
<input type="text" id="positive" name="positive">
<br />
Total -:<br />
<input type="text" id="negative" name="negative">
<br />
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).on('change', '[name^=pn]', function selectQuantity(selectedValue){
  var e = document.getElementsByName('pn[]');
  var quantity = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

  if ( quantity==='0') {
    document.getElementById('positive').value = "";
    document.getElementById('negative').value = "";

  } else if ( quantity==='1') {
    document.getElementById('positive').value = "";
    document.getElementById('negative').value = "";
    var numVal1 = Number(document.getElementsByName("p[]").value);
      var totalValue1 = numVal1
      let total = 0;
      for(const el of document.getElementsByName("p[]"))
      total += +el.value;
      document.getElementById("positive").value = total.toFixed(2);

  } else { 
    document.getElementById("positive").value = "";
    document.getElementById("negative").value = "";
    var numVal2 = Number(document.getElementsByName("p[]").value);
      var totalValue2 = numVal2
      let total = 0;
      for(const el of document.getElementsByName("p[]"))
      total += +el.value;
      document.getElementById("positive").value = total.toFixed(2);
  }
});
</script>
```

Does someone know why my script is not working properly?

Answer (score 0):

That codes a mess spellos and bad organisation, this might be what you are looking for:

```js
$('[name^=pn]').on('change', function() {
 let neg = 0
 let pos = 0

 $('[name^=pn]').each( function( i, e) {
  var quantity = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

  if ( quantity==='0') {

  } else if ( quantity==='1') {
   var num = Number( document.getElementById( $(this).data('target')).value);
   pos += num;

  } else {
   var num = Number(this.value);
   neg += num;

  }

 });

 document.getElementById('positive').value = pos;
 document.getElementById('negative').value = neg;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Price 1:<br />
<input type="text" id="p1" name="p[]">
<select id="pn1" name="pn[]" data-target="p1">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="1">+</option>
  <option value="2">-</option>
</select>
<br />
Price 2:<br />
<input type="text" id="p2" name="p[]">
<select id="pn2" name="pn[]" data-target="p2">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="1">+</option>
  <option value="2">-</option>
</select>
<br />
Price 3:<br />
<input type="text" id="p3" name="p[]">
<select id="pn3" name="pn[]" data-target="p3">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="1">+</option>
  <option value="2">-</option>
</select>
<br /><br />
Total +:<br />
<input type="text" id="positive" name="positive">
<br />
Total -:<br />
<input type="text" id="negative" name="negative">
<br />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer for you with vanilla JS. I commented the JS code so you could see what I did at each step. I changed your HTML as well by making the inputs have type "number" instead of "text". That way you can't have the user enter letters into the box by accident. It makes error checking a little easier later on. I also changed the place where you display the totals to be paragraphs instead of text boxes, so that the user can't enter anything in there. As a general rule, I don't like to use an input unless the user is supposed to enter something there.

```js
//declare shortcuts
const inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
const selects = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
const ipr = "p";
const spr = "pn";
//loop through and add event listeners to all text boxes and dropdowns
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener("input", Compute)
}
for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
  selects[i].addEventListener("change", Compute)
}
function Compute() {
  //set total positive and negative to zero
  let pos = 0;
  let neg = 0;
  //loop through each text box-dropdown combo
  for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    //determine if sign is positive or negative and add or subtract accordingly
    switch (document.getElementById(spr + i).value) {
      case "1":
        pos = pos + Number(document.getElementById(ipr + i).value);
        break;
      case "2":
        neg = neg - Number(document.getElementById(ipr + i).value);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
  //display each total on the page
  document.getElementById("positive").innerHTML = pos;
  document.getElementById("negative").innerHTML = neg;
}
```

```html
Price 1:<br />
<input type="number" id="p1" name="p[]">
<select id="pn1" name="pn[]">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="1">+</option>
  <option value="2">-</option>
</select>
<br />
Price 2:<br />
<input type="number" id="p2" name="p[]">
<select id="pn2" name="pn[]">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="1">+</option>
  <option value="2">-</option>
</select>
<br />
Price 3:<br />
<input type="number" id="p3" name="p[]">
<select id="pn3" name="pn[]">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="1">+</option>
  <option value="2">-</option>
</select>
<br /><br />
Total +:<br />
<p id="positive">0</p>
Total -:<br />
<p id="negative">0</p>
```